# Inductive Proof of $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\varphi$ iff $\varphi\in V$ (Modal Case)

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, modal-logic

This post is regarding the proof of $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\varphi$ iff $\varphi\in V$ in *Reasoning about Knowledge*, by Fagin, Halpern, Moses, & Vardi. This is used in showing that K$_n$ is a sound and complete axiomatization with respect to $\mathcal M_n$ for formulas in the language $\mathcal L_n$.

I need help understanding the **modal case** of the inductive proof of $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\varphi$ iff $\varphi\in V$ ($\color{red}{\text{highlighted in red}}$ below), but I shall provide the entire proof of Theorem $3.1.3$ for context.

---

> **Theorem:** K$_n$ is a sound and complete axiomatization with respect to $\mathcal M_n$ for formulas in the language $\mathcal L_n$.
> **Proof:**
> It is easy to prove by induction on the length of proof of $\varphi$ that if $\varphi$ is provable in K$_n$, then $\varphi$ is valid with respect to $\mathcal{M}_n$. It follows that K$_n$ is **sound** with respect to $\mathcal{M}_n$.
>
> To prove completeness, we must show that every formula in $\mathcal{L}_n$ that is valid with respect to $\mathcal{M}_n$ is provable in K$_n$. It suffices to prove that
> $$\begin{align}
>     \text{Every K}_n\text{-consistent formula in }\mathcal{L}_n\text{ is satisfiable with respect to}\mathcal{M}_n. \quad(\bigstar)
> \end{align}$$
> Suppose we can prove $(\bigstar)$, and $\varphi$ is a valid formula in $\mathcal{L}_n$. If $\varphi$ is not provable in K$_n$, then neither is $\lnot\lnot \varphi$. By definition, $\lnot\varphi$ is K$_n$-consistent. It follows from $(\bigstar)$ that $\lnot\varphi$ is satisfiable with respect to $\mathcal{M}_n$, contradicting the validity of $\varphi$ with respect to $\mathcal{M}_n$.
>
> We prove $(\bigstar)$ by constructing a special structure $M^c\in\mathcal{M}_n$, called the canonical structure for K$_n$. $M^c$ has a state $s_V$ corresponding to every maximal K$_n$ consistent set $V$. Then we show
> $$\begin{align}
>     (M^c,s_V)\vDash \varphi \text{ if and only if }\varphi\in V. \quad(\bigstar\bigstar) 
> \end{align}$$
> Note that $(\bigstar\bigstar)$ is sufficient to prove $(\bigstar)$, for if $\varphi$ is K$_n$-consistent, then $\varphi$ is contained in some maximal K$_n$-consistent set $V$. From $(\bigstar\bigstar)$ it follows that $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\varphi$ and so $\varphi$ is satisfiable in $M^c$. Therefore, $\varphi$ is satisfiable with respect to $\mathcal{M}_n$, as desired.
>
> Given a set $V$ of formulas, define $K/V_i = \{\varphi: K_i\varphi\in V\}$. Let $M^c = (S,\pi,R_1,\ldots, R_n)$ where
> $$\begin{align*}
>     S &= \{s_V: V \text{ is a maximal K$_n$-consistent set} \}\\
>     \pi(s_V)(p) &= \begin{cases}T & \text{if }p\in V\\
>     F& \text{if }p\notin V\end{cases}\\
>     R_i = \{(s_V,s_W): V/K_i \subseteq W\}.
> \end{align*}$$
> We now show that for every $s_V\in S$ we have $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\varphi$ if and only if $\varphi\in V$. We proceed by induction on the structure of formulas. Assuming that the claim holds for all subformulas of $\varphi$, we show that it also holds for $\varphi$.
>
> If $\varphi$ is a primitive proposition $p$, the claim follows immediately from the definition of $\pi(s_V)$.
>
> Suppose $\varphi = \psi_1 \land \psi_2$. $(M^c,s_V)\vDash \psi_1\land\psi_2$ iff $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\psi_1$ and $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\psi_2$. By the induction hypothesis, $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\psi_1$ iff $\psi_1\in V$ and $(M^c,s_V)\vDash\psi_2$ iff $\psi_2\in V$. Since $V$ is maximally K$_n$-consistent, $\psi_1\in V$ and $\psi_2\in V$ iff $\psi_1\land\psi_2\in V$. As a result, $(M^c,s_V)\vDash \psi_1\land\psi_2$ if and only if $\psi_1\land\psi_2\in V$.
>
> Suppose $\varphi = \lnot\psi$. $(M^c,s_V)\vDash \lnot\psi$ iff $(M^c,s_V)\not\vDash\psi$. By the induction hypothesis, $(M^c,s_V)\not\vDash\psi$ iff $\psi\notin V$. Since $V$ is maximally K$_n$-consistent, $\psi\notin V$ iff $\lnot\psi\in V$. So, $(M^c,s_V)\vDash \lnot\psi$ if and only if $\lnot\psi\in V$.
>
> Suppose $\varphi = K_i\psi$ and $\varphi\in V$. Then, $\psi\in V/K_i$ and by the definition of $R_i$, if $(s_V,s_W)\in R_i$ then $\psi\in W$. Thus, by using the induction hypothesis, $(M^c,s_W)\vDash\psi$ for all $W$ such that $(s_V,s_W)\in R_i$. By definition of $\vDash$, it follows that $(M^c,s_V)\vDash K_i\psi$.

$\color{red}{\text{The forward direction of the modal case begins here.}}$
$\color{red}{\text{This is the part I need help with. Everything before this is only for context.}}$

> Suppose $\varphi = K_i\psi$ and $(M^c,s_V)\vDash K_i\psi$. It follows that the set $(V/K_i)\cup\{\lnot\psi\}$ is not K$_n$-consistent. For suppose otherwise. Then it would have a maximal K$_n$-consistent extension $W$ and, by construction, we would have $(s_V,s_W)\in R_i$. By the induction hypothesis, we have $(M^c,s_W)\vDash\lnot\psi$ and so $(M^c,s_V)\vDash \lnot K_i\psi$, contradicting our original assumption. Since $(V/K_i)\cup\{\lnot\psi\}$ is not K$_n$-consistent, there must be some finite subset say $\{\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_k,\lnot\psi\}$ which is not K$_n$-consistent. Thus, by propositional reasoning, we have
> $$\text{K}_n\vdash \varphi_1 \to (\varphi_2 \to (\ldots \to (\varphi_k\to\psi)\ldots)).$$

1. **How do we arrive at** $\text{K}_n\vdash \varphi_1 \to (\varphi_2 \to (\ldots \to (\varphi_k\to\psi)\ldots))$? Could someone kindly provide a **detailed argument**?

> By the Knowledge Generalization Axiom, we have
> $$\text{K}_n\vdash K_i(\varphi_1 \to (\varphi_2 \to (\ldots \to (\varphi_k\to\psi)\ldots))).$$
> By induction on $k$, together with axiom (A2) and propositional reasoning, we can show
> $$\text{K}_n\vdash K_i(\varphi_1\to (\varphi_2 \to (\ldots \to (\varphi_k\to \psi)\ldots )) \implies (K_i\varphi_1\to (K_i\varphi_2 \to (\ldots \to (K_i\varphi_k\to K_i\psi)\ldots))).$$

2. **What exactly is the induction argument** involved here? Could someone please help fill in the details?

> Now from Modus Ponens we get
> $$\text{K}_n\vdash K_i\varphi_1\to (K_i\varphi_2 \to (\ldots \to (K_i\varphi_k\to K_i\psi)\ldots))$$
> $K_i\varphi_1\to (K_i\varphi_2 \to (\ldots \to (K_i\varphi_k\to K_i\psi)\ldots)) \in V$.
> Since $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_k\in V/K_i$, we must have $K_i\varphi_1, \ldots, K_i\varphi_k \in V$. It follows that $K_i\psi\in V$ as desired.

Thanks a lot! I know this is a really long post, but I'd really appreciate any help with my two questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. ad Q1**

Suppose $\{ \varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_k, \neg \psi \}$ is a $K_n$-inconsistent subset of $V/K_i \cup \{ \neg \psi \}$. Then

> $\vdash_{K_n} \neg(\varphi_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \varphi_k \wedge \neg \psi)$.

By propositional reasoning we have that

> $\vdash_{K_n} \neg \varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \neg \varphi_k \lor \psi$.

Since $\vdash_{K_n} (\neg \varphi_k \lor \psi) \leftrightarrow (\varphi_k \rightarrow \psi)$, we can conclude that

> $\vdash_{K_n} \neg \varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \neg \varphi_{k-1} \lor (\varphi_k \rightarrow \psi)$.

Again, as $\vdash_{K_n} (\neg \varphi_{k-1} \lor (\varphi_k \rightarrow \psi)) \leftrightarrow (\varphi_{k-1} \rightarrow (\varphi_k \rightarrow \psi))$ it follows that

> $\vdash_{K_n} \neg \varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \neg \varphi_{k-2} \lor (\varphi_{k-1} \rightarrow (\varphi_k \rightarrow \psi))$.

Iterating this procedure $k-2$ times we arrive at

> $\vdash_{K_n} \varphi_1 \rightarrow (\varphi_2 \rightarrow (\ldots \rightarrow(\varphi_k \rightarrow \psi) \ldots))$.

**2. ad Q2**

The induction base is trivial: For $k=1$ the desired result, namely

> $\vdash_{K_n} K_i(\varphi_1 \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (K_i \varphi_1 \rightarrow K_i \psi)$,

is an instance of the K-axiom. For the induction step, assume the claim holds for all $n < k$. We show it also holds for $k$ by constructing a $K_n$-proof (some notes on proof presentation: every numbered line is thought to the claim that the formula in that line is $K_n$-provable; justifications for provability claims are given at the end of each line; the label PC means that the provability claim is justified by propositional reasoning):

1. $K_i(\varphi_1 \rightarrow ( \varphi_2 \rightarrow( \ldots \rightarrow ( \varphi_k \rightarrow \psi) \ldots))) \rightarrow (K_i\varphi_1 \rightarrow K_i( \varphi_2 \rightarrow( \ldots \rightarrow ( \varphi_k \rightarrow \psi) \ldots)))$, K-axiom
2. $K_i(\varphi_2 \rightarrow( \ldots \rightarrow ( \varphi_k \rightarrow \psi) \ldots)) \rightarrow (K_i\varphi_2 \rightarrow( \ldots \rightarrow (K_i \varphi_k \rightarrow K_i \psi)))$, induction hypothesis
3. $K_i \varphi_1 \rightarrow (K_i( \varphi_2 \rightarrow (\ldots \rightarrow (\varphi_k \rightarrow \psi ) \ldots )) \rightarrow [K_i \varphi_1 \rightarrow (K_i \varphi_2 \rightarrow (\ldots \rightarrow (K_i\varphi_k \rightarrow K_i \psi)))]$, PC 2
4. $K_i(\varphi_1 \rightarrow ( \varphi_2 \rightarrow( \ldots \rightarrow ( \varphi_k \rightarrow \psi) \ldots)))\rightarrow [K_i \varphi_1 \rightarrow (K_i \varphi_2 \rightarrow (\ldots \rightarrow (K_i\varphi_k \rightarrow K_i \psi)))]$, PC 1,3

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide a lazy answer in a sense that, instead of trying to work through the proof from the textbook, I will provide the one I like and use.

So, the truth lemma goes as follows:

**Truth Lemma** For all mcs' $\Gamma$ and all $\varphi \in \mathcal{K}$ (the language of logic $\mathbf{K}$) it holds that $\varphi \in \Gamma$ iff $\mathfrak{M}^C_{\Gamma} \models \varphi$ ($\varphi$ holds in state $\Gamma$ of the canonical model).

*Proof.* Base case follows from the definition of the canonical model.

*Induction hypothesis*. For all proper subformulas $\psi$ of $\varphi$ we have that $\psi \in \Gamma$ iff $\mathfrak{M}^c_{\Gamma} \models \psi$. (I assume that the subformula relation is defined as a well-founded strict partial order)

*Case* $\psi:= \square_a \chi$. *From left to right*: Assume that $\square_a \chi \in \Gamma$. By the definition of the canonical model this means that $\chi \in \Delta$ for all $\Delta$ such that $\Gamma \setminus \square_a \subseteq \Delta$. By the induction hypothesis and the definition of the canonical model, the latter is equivalent to $\mathfrak{M}^c_\Delta \models \chi$ for all $\Delta$ such that $\Gamma \sim_a \Delta$. Finally, the latter is equivalent to $\mathfrak{M}^c_{\Gamma} \models \square_a \chi$ by the semantics.

*From right to left*: Assume that $\mathfrak{M}^c_{\Gamma} \models \square_a \chi$. By the semantics this is equivalent to the fact that for all $\Delta$ such that $\Gamma \sim_a \Delta$, $\mathfrak{M}^c_{\Delta} \models \chi$. By the definition of the canonical model and the induction hypothesis, the latter is equivalent to the fact that for all $\Delta$ such that $\Gamma \setminus \square_a \subseteq \Delta$, $\chi \in \Delta$. Now we need to show that $\square_a \chi \in \Gamma$. Suppose towards a contradiction that $\square_a \chi \not \in \Gamma$, and hence $\chi \not \in \Gamma \setminus \square_a$.

**Small fact about** $\Gamma \setminus \square_a$: set $\Gamma \setminus \square_a$ contains all theorems of $\mathbf{K}$ and is closed under R1. This can be shown using the fact that if some $\tau$ is a theorem, $\square_a \tau$ is a theorem as well, and using the distributivity of $\square_a$.

**Another useful sublemma**: $\Gamma \setminus \square_a \cup \{\tau\}$ is consistent iff $\lnot \tau \not \in \Gamma \setminus \square_a$. This can be shown using the fact that $\Gamma \setminus \square_a \subseteq \Gamma \setminus \square_a \cup \{\tau\}$.

Once we have this, the proof follows easily. Recall that we have $\chi \not \in \Gamma \setminus \square_a$. By **another useful lemma**, this is equivalent to $\Gamma \setminus \square_a \cup \{\lnot \chi\}$ being consistent. Then, according to Lindenbaum Lemma, this consistent set can be extended to a mcs $\Delta^\prime$ such that $\Gamma \setminus \square_a \subseteq \Delta^\prime$ and $\lnot \chi \in \Delta^\prime$. A contradiction.

Comment: I'll try to understand this (I think you've followed Blackburn's approach). Meanwhile it would be really great if you can help me specifically answer my Q1 and Q2 as asked in the post directly too!

Comment: Also, why is it true that if a formula $\varphi$ is $AX$-consistent, then $\varphi$ is satisfiable in the canonical structure/model for $AX$? This may or may not be related, but I see this property being utilized often in this section of the book.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor the canonical model is a kind of super-model with all possible consistent valuations of all formulas as its states. So, if a formula is consistent, meaning that it is not equivalent to a contradiction, then there is always a mcs that contains it. Such an mcs is a state in the canonical model, and hence, by the truth lemma, the formula is satisfied in the state.

Comment: There is just one place where our definitions differ, Charles. A formula $\phi$ is $AX$-consistent if $\lnot\phi$ is not provable in $AX$, i.e. $AX\not\vdash\lnot\phi$. Using this, can you elaborate more on why - "if a formula is consistent, there is an MCS that contains it."? After this I can use the truth lemma.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor if I understand your question correctly, then $\varphi$ is consistent means that we cannot prove $\lnot \varphi$ in a given axiomatic system, that is $AX \not \vdash \lnot \varphi$. So, if $\varphi$ is consistent, it should belong to some mcs $V$. Such a $V$ is a state in the canonical model. The truth lemma (what you have written in the display mode) says that $\varphi$ belonging to some mcs $V$ is equivalent to $\varphi$ being satisfied in the canonical model in state $V$

Comment: I completely agree! But why is this true: **"if a formula is consistent, there is an MCS that contains it."**?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor well, if $\varphi$ is consistent, then set $\{\varphi\}$ is consistent. By Lindenbaum lemma, this set can be extended to a maximal consistent set.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much!